# I customized the Registration Form in Laravel Breeze, but it does not allow me to Register a User

Tags: laravel, breeze

Install Laravel 10.1.3 with PHP 8.2.3 on a Docker Desktop.

To handle App authentication, install Breeze and modify the "register.blade.php and login.blade.php" views to customize the user registration and login forms.

The "Registration" and "Login" views, in addition to their code, were as follows:

**register.blade.php**

```
<x-guest-layout>
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('register') }}" novalidate>
    @csrf

    <!-- Document -->
    <div>
        <x-input-label class="mt-2" for="document" :value="__('Document')" />
        <x-text-input id="document" class="block mt-1 w-full" type="text" name="document" placeholder="Número de Identificación" :value="old('document')" required autofocus autocomplete="document" />
        <x-input-error :messages="$errors->get('document')" class="mt-2" />
    </div>

    <!-- First Name -->
    <div>
        <x-input-label class="mt-2" for="firstName" :value="__('FirstName')" />
        <x-text-input id="firstName" class="block mt-1 w-full" type="text" name="firstName" placeholder="Nombres" :value="old('firstName')" required autofocus autocomplete="firstName" />
        <x-input-error :messages="$errors->get('firstName')" class="mt-2" />
    </div>

    <!-- Last Name -->
    <div>
        <x-input-label class="mt-2" for="lastName" :value="__('LastName')" />
        <x-text-input id="lastName" class="block mt-1 w-full" type="text" name="lastName" placeholder="Apellidos" :value="old('lastName')" required autofocus autocomplete="lastName" />
        <x-input-error :messages="$errors->get('lastName')" class="mt-2" />
    </div>

    <!-- Email Address -->
    <div class="mt-4">
        <x-input-label for="email" :value="__('Email')" />
        <x-text-input id="email" class="block mt-1 w-full" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Correo electrónico" :value="old('email')" required autocomplete="username" />
        <x-input-error :messages="$errors->get('email')" class="mt-2" />
    </div>

    <!-- Rol -->
    <div class="mt-4">
        <x-input-label for="rol" :value="__('Rol')" />
        <select class="border-gray-300 focus:border-indigo-500 focus:ring-indigo-500 rounded-md shadow-sm block mt-1 w-full" id="rol" name="rol">
            <option value="">-- Seleccione un Rol --</option>
            <option value="1">Administrador de Sistema</option>
            <option value="2">Administrador</option>
            <option value="3">Administrador de Jardín</option>
            <option value="4">Comercial</option>
            <option value="5">Logístico</option>
            <option value="6">Académico</option>
        </select>
        {{-- <x-text-input id="email" class="block mt-1 w-full" type="email" name="email" :value="old('email')" required autocomplete="username" /> --}}
        <x-input-error :messages="$errors->get('rol')" class="mt-2" />
    </div>

    <!-- Password -->
    <div class="mt-4">
        <x-input-label for="password" :value="__('Password')" />

        <x-text-input id="password" class="block mt-1 w-full"
                        type="password"
                        name="password"
                        placeholder="Contraseña"
                        required autocomplete="new-password" />

        <x-input-error :messages="$errors->get('password')" class="mt-2" />
    </div>

    <!-- Confirm Password -->
    <div class="mt-4">
        <x-input-label for="password_confirmation" :value="__('Confirm Password')" />

        <x-text-input id="password_confirmation" class="block mt-1 w-full"
                        type="password"
                        name="password_confirmation" placeholder="Confirme Contraseña" required autocomplete="new-password" />

        <x-input-error :messages="$errors->get('password_confirmation')" class="mt-2" />
    </div>

    <div class="flex items-center justify-end mt-4">
        <a class="underline text-sm text-gray-600 hover:text-gray-900 rounded-md focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-indigo-500" href="{{ route('login') }}">
            {{ __('Already registered?') }}
        </a>

        <x-primary-button class="ml-4">
            {{ __('Register') }}
        </x-primary-button>
    </div>
</form>
</x-guest-layout>
```

[image]

**login.blade.php**

```
<x-guest-layout>
<!-- Session Status -->
<x-auth-session-status class="mb-4" :status="session('status')" />

<form method="POST" action="{{ route('login') }}" novalidate>
    @csrf
    
    <!-- Document -->
    <div>
        <x-input-label class="mt-2" for="document" :value="__('Document')" />
        <x-text-input id="document" class="block mt-1 w-full" type="text" name="document" placeholder="Número de Identificación" :value="old('document')" required autofocus autocomplete="document" />
        <x-input-error :messages="$errors->get('document')" class="mt-2" />
    </div>

    <!-- Password -->
    <div class="mt-4">
        <x-input-label for="password" :value="__('Password')" />

        <x-text-input id="password" class="block mt-1 w-full"
                        type="password"
                        name="password"
                        placeholder="Contraseña"
                        required autocomplete="current-password" />

        <x-input-error :messages="$errors->get('password')" class="mt-2" />
    </div>

    <!-- Remember Me -->
    <div class="block mt-4">
        <label for="remember_me" class="inline-flex items-center">
            <input id="remember_me" type="checkbox" class="rounded border-gray-300 text-indigo-600 shadow-sm focus:ring-indigo-500" name="remember">
            <span class="ml-2 text-sm text-gray-600">{{ __('Remember me') }}</span>
        </label>
    </div>

    <div class="flex items-center justify-end mt-4">
        @if (Route::has('password.request'))
            <a class="underline text-sm text-gray-600 hover:text-gray-900 rounded-md focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-indigo-500" href="{{ route('password.request') }}">
                {{ __('Forgot your password?') }}
            </a>
        @endif

        <x-primary-button class="ml-3">
            {{ __('Log in') }}
        </x-primary-button>
    </div>
</form>
</x-guest-layout>
```

[image]

After this, I created two migrations that added the new fields of the Registration and Login forms in the "create_users_table.php" table.

The migrations created are the following:

**add_rol_to_users_table.php**

```
<?php

    use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
    use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

    return new class extends Migration
    {
        /**
         * Run the migrations.
         */
        public function up(): void
        {
            Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
                $table->integer('rol');
                //1 = Administrador de Sistema
                //2 = Administrador
                //3 = Administrador de Jardín
                //4 = Comercial
                //5 = Logístico
                //6 = Académico
            });
        }
    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     */
    public function down(): void
    {
        Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->dropColumn('rol');
        });
    }
};
```

**add_document_first_name_last_name_to_users_table.php**

```
<?php

    use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
    use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

    return new class extends Migration
    {
        /**
         * Run the migrations.
         */
        public function up(): void
        {
            Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
                $table->string('document')->unique();
                $table->string('firstName');
                $table->string('lastName');
            });
        }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     */
    public function down(): void
    {
        Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->dropColumn('document');
            $table->dropColumn('firstName');
            $table->dropColumn('lastName');
        });
    }
};
```

Then, add these new fields in the "App/Models/user.php" which looks like this:

**user.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

// use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasApiTokens, HasFactory, Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array<int, string>
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'document',
        'firstName',
        'lastName',
        'email',
        'rol',
        'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for serialization.
     *
     * @var array<int, string>
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast.
     *
     * @var array<string, string>
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];
}
```

Then modify the "App/Http/Controllers/Auth/RegisteredUserController.php" to create these fields in the controller and add validations to them.

The controller was as follows:

**registeredUserController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\View\View;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Validation\Rules;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse;
use Illuminate\Auth\Events\Registered;
use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;

class RegisteredUserController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display the registration view.
     */
    public function create(): View
    {
        return view('auth.register');
    }

    /**
     * Handle an incoming registration request.
     *
     * @throws \Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException
     */
    public function store(Request $request): RedirectResponse
    {
        $request->validate([
            'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'document' => ['required', 'string', 'max:10'],
            'firstName' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'lastName' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:'.User::class],
            'rol' => ['required', 'numeric', 'between:1,6'],
            'password' => ['required', 'confirmed', Rules\Password::defaults()],
        ]);

        $user = User::create([
            'name' => $request->name,
            'document' => $request->document,
            'firstName' => Str::upper($request->firstName),
            'lastName' => Str::upper($request->lastName),
            'email' => $request->email,
            'rol' => $request->rol,
            'password' => Hash::make($request->password),
        ]);

        event(new Registered($user));

        Auth::login($user);

        return redirect(RouteServiceProvider::HOME);
    }
}
```

And finally I ran the migrations using the "sail artisan migrate" command as indicated by the Laravel documentation.

In theory, if I fill out the "Registration" form and click on the "REGISTER" button, the new user would be registered and his data would go to the database, but that is not happening.

I use DBeaver to check if the information arrives in the Database, but nothing is recorded.

[image]

Also, when the "REGISTER" button is clicked it stays in the same window of the registration form and does not go to the Dashboard window, as it normally should.

I have looked at the Laravel documentation and followed all the steps indicated there, but it has not worked, I have also researched on the internet on the subject, but documentation is needed on this problem. I think it may be something that I might overlook, that's why I have sent the code of everything that I have modified in the project to see if you see something inside the code that I could not see and I need to modify.

In summary, I need help in three specific things:

1. Get you to register new users.
2. Disable the user account creation confirmation that the Breeze asks for via email.
3. Being able to perform user login with the document number and password.

I really appreciate your help with this inconvenience.

Answer (score 0):

Because in RegisteredUserController user created like this

```
User::create([
    'name' => $request->name,
    'email' => $request->email,
    'password' => Hash::make($request->password)
]);
```